# Kubernetes expose an app via a DNS name in minicube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a Minikube installation in which I created a simple hello-world deployment like this:

```
kubectl create deployment hello-node \
    --image=gcr.io/hello-minikube-zero-install/hello-node
```

I exposed the deployment via a service in the following way:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

Now If I call: `http://<local cluster ip>:8080` it prints "Hello World!" as expected.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to expose different deployments in the same cluster to different sub-domains of the cluster. For instance, deployment `hello1` to `hello1.my-k8-cluster.com`, `hello2` to `hello2.my-k8-cluster.com`.

I want to test this locally because later I will do the same on a real cluster.

**Question:** How to test DNS configurations of services locally? How to define sub-domains in services?

**What I tried so far:**
I went through the how-to guides [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-deployment) and [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) which though didn't bring me a clear picture on how to configure what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've seen work for this is to use Nginx as the LoadBalancer and defining the Ingress with type NodePort for the different services.  You can see a tutorial that shows the first steps for setting this up [here](https://medium.com/@awkwardferny/getting-started-with-kubernetes-ingress-nginx-on-minikube-d75e58f52b6c).

Additionally, the official docs [DNS for Service and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and [Customizing DNS Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/) are good resources.